# ITCL - How to access associative array member inside a class?

Tags: tcl, incr-tcl

How to access associative array member of a class inside the class itself? Itcl is modeled after C++, and in C++ we would write:

```
SomeObject.SomePublicMember = ...
```

How to do the same in Itcl? Without providing accessor procedure for such an array. I've seen that for usual plain variables this can be obtained by using cget:

```
$this cget -PublicMemberVariableName
```

However the following construct doesn't work:

```
$this cget -AssociativeArrayName(NamedIndex)
```

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

Alas, cget won't get what you want.  The array element isn't passed all the way down to ItclGetInstanceVar (I'm not sure why).

You *can* use get/set and the like:

```
class myObject {
   public variable AssArray
   constructor {} {
      array set AssArray ""
   }
   method setArr { elem val } {
      set AssArray($elem) $val
   }
   method getArr { elem } {
      return $AssArray($elem)
   }
   method getFullArr {} {
      return [array names AssArray]
}
```